# How to install pandas in a Windows 10 PC without internet/Anaconda(or any similar freeware)?

Tags: python, pandas, installation

I've a windows 10 PC which is not connected to internet. However, I can transfer files to it.
I've already installed python 3.8.1 directly. Whenever I try to install pandas using pip (Already downloaded pandas-1.0.1.tar.gz file from PyPI), error pops up due to dependencies.

Comment: Pandas depends on [a lot of packages](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/requirements-dev.txt). In theory, you can go through the list and install them one and after another but that's not trivial. You need C/C++ compilers and the whole machinery behind it. That being said, you can try moving your preferred Anaconda environment, read more [here](https://www.anaconda.com/moving-conda-environments/).

Comment: But  how is creating/cloning/moving the environment with required packages possible  without internet? It checks for the package over internet.

Comment: You said you can transfer files to it. The idea here is that you setup your environment on a machine that have internet access, then package it and transfer it to your offline machine, and unpack it there. The documentation that I linked to describes this.

Answer (score -2):

You can install it from the source but keep in mind that you must install its requirements too. There is a link provided for describing intallation from source:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/install.html

Comment: I've installed the following dependencies using the binary files, except NumPy.
setuptools-24.2.0
NumPy-1.13.3
python-dateutil-2.6.1
pytz-2017.2

When I try to install NumPy , similar error pops up. I think it is because of the dependencies of NumPy pacakage. I suppose, it requires Cython & Cython is dependent on Microsoft Visual C++ and similarly the list goes on.

Is there any bundle with all of these binary together?
Installation is quite difficult if we follow with binaries of each dependent package.